# Sort List of Tuples Containing Strings By First Element Float (Python)

Tags: python, list, sorting, floating-point, tuples

I have a long list of tuples:

```
[...
(0.862, 'beehive', 'bug'),
(0.12, 'yard', 'property'),
(0.0, 'lake', 'mailbox'),
(0.37, 'maintenance', 'shears'),
(0.1666, 'summer', 'popsicle'),
(0.9, 'poplar', 'tree')
...]
```

and I need to sort this list descending by the float values. I know the Python automatically sorts lists by the first value, however even when I call sorted or even explicitly specify the first element, I haven't had success.

```
sorted(mylist) # doesn't sort the list at all

sorted(mylist, key = x[0]) # on this sort attempt I get "'str' object is not callable"
```

Can anyone provide detail as to why the list is still disorganized despite these sorting attempts and what might sort by floats in descending order?

Comment: `sorted(..)` returns a *new* list.

Comment: ... and for descending you want `reverse=True`...

Comment: About the `key` not working: you need to provide a callable, like this: `key=lambda x: x[0]`, or `key=itertools.itemgetter(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sorted(..)` returns a *new* list. What you are looking for is `.sort(..)` to sort the list *inplace*.

Furthermore you can use the `reverse` parameter to sort in descending order:

```
data.sort(reverse=True)  # sort the list inplace
```

This will return:

```
>>> data.sort(reverse=True)
>>> data
[(0.9, 'poplar', 'tree'), (0.862, 'beehive', 'bug'), (0.37, 'maintenance', 'shears'), (0.1666, 'summer', 'popsicle'), (0.12, 'yard', 'property'), (0.0, 'lake', 'mailbox')]
```

The default sorting of tuples will *first sort on the first elements*. If these are equal, it will consider the second element of each tuple and so on.

If you do not want this tie breaker, but use the *original* order in that case, you can use an `itemgetter` as `key`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

data.sort(reverse=True,key=itemgetter(0))  # sort the list inplace
```

You can use the *same* arguments with `sorted(..)` if you want to construct a *new* list that is sorted:

```
data_sorted = sorted(data,reverse=True)  # construct a new sorted list
```

Comment: Thanks again Willem - I think I was inadvertently seeking a more complicated answer than necessary. Appreciate the simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
data = [
(0.862, 'beehive', 'bug'),
(0.12, 'yard', 'property'),
(0.0, 'lake', 'mailbox'),
(0.37, 'maintenance', 'shears'),
(0.1666, 'summer', 'popsicle'),
(0.9, 'poplar', 'tree')
]

print(*reversed(sorted(data)))
```

Output :

```
(0.9, 'poplar', 'tree') (0.862, 'beehive', 'bug') (0.37, 'maintenance', 'shears') (0.1666, 'summer', 'popsicle') (0.12, 'yard', 'property') (0.0, 'lake', 'mailbox')
```

**Or,** You can follow another process :

```
>>> data = [
... (0.862, 'beehive', 'bug'),
... (0.12, 'yard', 'property'),
... (0.0, 'lake', 'mailbox'),
... (0.37, 'maintenance', 'shears'),
... (0.1666, 'summer', 'popsicle'),
... (0.9, 'poplar', 'tree')
... ]
>>> data.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0], reverse = True)
>>> data
[(0.9, 'poplar', 'tree'), (0.862, 'beehive', 'bug'), (0.37, 'maintenance', 'shears'), (0.1666, 'summer', 'popsicle'), (0.12, 'yard', 'property'), (0.0, 'lake', 'mailbox')]
>>>
```